# Bootstrap list items not getting css

Tags: css, navbar

I got a issue if I want to add a list item in my navbar its not getting the same as the example on the website. I use the same code but When I use the css for the navbar its working but list item are not getting the css applied. I already tried to reload the css but still the same

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
    <div class="nav navbar-nav">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I get it like this
http://puu.sh/pNzfA/1c78934d68.png

Comment: could you place your updated code with css in fiddle

Comment: Where are you sourcing bootstrap from? CDN or Downloaded?

Comment: You're not getting the Bootstrap css ? or your own css ?

Comment: Its downloaded the issue is other parts of bootstrap are working fine but only the list items are not getting positioned like the examples on the boostrap website.

Comment: We need to see your code

Comment: First try clearing your cache and if after that it still doesn't want to behave nicely. Try apply different bootstrap classes and see if they style appropriately, if not then you have a different issue

Comment: I just noticed if use the CDN link from boostrap the css get applied but im using the same CSS in the folder so this is very strange.

Comment: your question is about list item or navbar's dropdown menu ?????????inspect element using dev tools and target hidden <ul> and <li> tag and change css